# absorption laws don't understand it with Venn diagrams

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Absorption Law states $A∪(A∩B)=A$ and $A∩(A∪B)=A$.

I can't seem to picture these with Venn diagrams can someone help me out ? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use venn diagrams or do you just want to understand?

Comment: Did you draw the diagrams?

Comment: You probably need two/three Venn diagrams one on top of the other to appreciate the laws you have above.

Comment: looking for a venn diagram to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is best to combine a few diagrams to illustrate. Unfortunately my
CAD skills are limited.

The following shows $A \cap B$ and $A$ and the last is the union, which is
any point that is in either of the top two sets.

[image]

The second equality follows similarly.